# How to get average for each student in sql?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 2 tables - `Table1` and `Table2`:

```
Student ID   Student Name
-------------------------
12           John Smith
14           Raj Sharma
15           Lee Wang
16           Anan Obi

Student ID   Course           Points
-------------------------------------
12           Mathematics      86
14           Mathematics      75
16           Mathematics      96
16           Mathematics      97
15           Physics          92
15           Physics          65
12           Physics          63
16           Physics          58
14           Physics          78
14           Chemistry        83
15           Chemistry        65
12           Chemistry        95
12           Chemistry        90
```

I want to get average points per course for each student, sorted
by student names.

Resulting output should be:

```
| name       | course | avg (points) |
+------------+--------+--------------+
| Anan Obi   | Math   | 96.50000     |
| Anan Obi   | Phys   | 58.00000     |
| John Smith | Math   | 86.00000     |
| John Smith | Phys   | 63.00000     |
| John Smith | Chem   | 92.50000     |
| Lee Wang   | Phys   | 78.50000     |
| Lee Wang   | Chem   | 65.00000     |
| Raj Sharma | Math   | 75.00000     |
| Raj Sharma | Phys   | 78.00000     |
| Raj Sharma | Chem   | 83.00000     |
```

I tried the following code but not getting desired output:

```
select 
    t1.'student name', 
    t2.'course', avg(points) 
from 
    table1 t1, table2 t2 
group by 
    t2.Course 
order by 
    t1.'student name'
```

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: You are cross joining the tables. You want join on `[Student ID ]`

Comment: Please read [Bad habbits](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins)

Comment: Side note: Don't get used to use single quotes for identifiers such as column aliases. Yes, sadly SQL Server accepts that, but in SQL single quotes are usually for string (or date...) literals. Should you ever use another DBMS (or future SQL Server versions become more sane about this) you'll likely get an error. Use square brackets for identifiers that have special characters in them or are case sensitive or preferably don't use special characters and case sensitive identifiers at all. Identifiers don't need to be "pretty", "pretty" headers and such are a job for the presentation layer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Group by also over course

```
select s.[Student ID], s.[Student Name], sc.course, avg(sc.Points) 
from Students s
JOIN studentsCourse sc ON s.[Student ID]= sc.[Student ID]
Group by s.[Student ID], s.[Student Name], sc.course
order by s.[Student Name]
```

Comment: That's a right answer in general but you should also have a student's ID in the `GROUP BY` clause so that different students with the same name can be distinguished.

Comment: @stickybit, you're right

Answer (score 0):

Very simple by using Window Functions

```
SELECT
    t1.Student Name,
    AVG(t2.Points) OVER (PARTITION BY t1.Student Name,t2.course)
FROM
    t1
    LEFT JOIN t2 ON t1.Student ID=t2.Student ID
```

Comment: This is giving wrong output!